# Haskell: Generating a list of tuples (0..x, 0..y)

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to generate a list containing `[(0,0),..,(x-1,y-1)]` only given x and y.

The tuples are used to represent cells in a field of size (x,y).
e.g. (3,3) must return a list `[(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2)]`

I tried `[(0,0)...(3,3)]` because I really don't know how to do this in Haskell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A list is an instance of `Applicative`, and the sequential application acts as taking each function in the left list, each item in the right list, and yield the function applied to that item. We can generate such list with:

```
(,) <$> [0 .. 2] <*> [ 0 .. 2 ]
```

or with [**`liftA2 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA2):

```
import Control.Applicative(liftA2)

result = liftA2 (,) [0 .. 2] [0 .. 2]
```

or we can make use of *list comprehension*:

```
result = [ (x, y) | x <- [0 .. 2], y <- [0 .. 2] ]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foo a b = [(x, y) | x <- [0..a], y <- [0..b]]

Prelude> foo 2 2
```

> Out: [(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2)]